# How to create constants only once

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

It is trivial to write a macro to convert `bytes"hello"` into

`"hello".getBytes` or `Array('h'.getByte, 'o'.getByte, 'l'.getByte, 'l'.getByte, 'o'.getByte)`

The problem here is we do not get the constant literal, i.e
`"hello" eq "hello"` does not hold for the values constructed by the macros: `bytes"hello" ne bytes"hello"`. There is also a performance drawback as the byte array is needlessly constructed many times.

What actually `bytes"hello"` has to be converted is a global scope object:

```scala
object `bytes"hello"` {
  val value = Array('h'.getByte, 'o'.getByte, 'l'.getByte, 'l'.getByte, 'o'.getByte)
}
```

But it seems that in its current state, Scala Macros does not allow creation of global objects.
Am I wrong and this is doable in the current Scala ?

Comment: How important is it to you that the computation happen at compile time? If it's not important, you could defer to a runtime caching system.

Comment: It is important to create an object in a higher scope than the macro expansion.
Creating constants is just an example, not the problem to solve or to workaround.
There are many other application for the top-level objects made by macros: global caches, etc

Comment: Caching can be done at runtime. The point of macros is to do local code transformations, as I understand it, so I suspect that such global modifications are not possible.

Comment: I guess the trick could be done by macros + annotation processor, which could produce a new file